# Unpacking return unexpected result

Tags: smartpy, taquito, dapps

I'm having some issue with the contract read, i have data in format of sp.TMap(string,bytes), im using sp.pack() to get the bytes representation of a sp.TNat in a concrete example for a nat 200 y get as result 05008803, i been trying to decode the data using @TezosTaquito but couldn't get the result expected.

Also trying to replicate the encode of that nat @TezosTaquito don't give me the same bytes gotten from contract.

Using Tzip12 module neither work as expected.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For packing and unpacking michelson values, you can use the `@taquito/michel-codec` package.

**Example:**

```
const { packDataBytes, unpackDataBytes } = require("@taquito/michel-codec");

export function unpackData(bytes, type) {
  return unpackDataBytes({ bytes }, type);
}

export function packData(value, type) {
  return packDataBytes(value, type).bytes;
}

// Packing
packData({ int: 200 }, { prim: 'nat' }) // 05008803

// Unpacking
unpackData("05008803", { prim: "nat" }) // {"int":"200"}
```

Live example: https://codesandbox.io/s/elastic-cray-e8oviv?file=/src/index.js

Comment: Niceeee, 2nd time you save me bro, thanks very much for the help, if you are on NFT move i would like to gift you a piece of our up coming collection. You can contact me on twitter @M88ache. Thanks again

Comment: No need, just accept the answer if it helped you.

Comment: @MarceloDavidMoisés the best gifts on this stack exchange are green ticks and blue triangles ;)